# Can I check whether a bounded list contains duplicates, in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, complexity-theory

Suppose I have an `Int` list where elements are known to be bounded and the list is known to be no longer than their range, so that it is entirely possible for it not to contain duplicates. How can I test most quickly whether it is the case?

I know of [`nubOrd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Containers-ListUtils.html#v:nubOrd). It is [quite fast](https://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2015/02/nub-considered-harmful.html). We can pass our list through and see if it becomes shorter. But the efficiency of `nubOrd` is still not linear.

My idea is that we can trade space for time efficiency. Imperatively, we would allocate a bit field as wide as our range, and then traverse the list, marking the entries corresponding to the list elements' values. As soon as we try to flip a bit that is already 1, we return False. It only takes (read + compare + write) * length of the list. No binary search trees, no nothing.

Is it reasonable to attempt a similar construction in Haskell?

Comment: You could use a bitvector I think http://hackage.haskell.org/package/structures-0.2/docs/Data-Vector-Bit.html and use a mutable array and thus each time set a bit (and inspect that bit)

Comment: Of course it's reasonable. Is that your real question?

Comment: If you're allowed to modify the list, there is an O(n) algorithm that requires O(1) extra space.

Comment: @JimMischel Can you link me to it?

Comment: @DanielWagner I kind of asked two questions at once. The one in the title is pragmatically more useful, but I value the reassurance the answer to the one at the end would give me no less.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So the answer is "no"? _this is a joke due to the fact that this implementation of bit vector, for all its benefits, pulls along all of the `lens` dependencies_

Comment: @IgnatInsarov: I do not get why the fact that it pulls `Lens` dependencies is a problem? Lenses are frequently used to have an elegant view on containers. But you are not required to use lenses at all.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is hardly reasonable to expend so much computing power for such a seemingly simple problem.

Comment: Also there is this recently released [`bitvec` package](https://github.com/Bodigrim/bitvec)

Answer (score 3):

The [discrimination](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination) package has a linear time [nub](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination-0.4/docs/Data-Discrimination.html#v:nub) you can use. Or a linear time [group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination-0.4/docs/Data-Discrimination.html#v:group) that doesn't require the equivalent elements to be adjacent in order to group them, so you could see if any of the groups are not size 1.

The whole package is based on sidestepping the well known bounds on comparison-based sorts (and joins, and etc) by using algorithms based on "discrimination" rather than ones based on comparisons. As I understand it, the technique is somewhat like a [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), but generalised to ADTs.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a list of size N, and you know that the elements in the list are within the range `min .. min+N-1`.

There is a simple linear time algorithm that requires O(1) space.

First, scan the list to find the minimum and maximum elements.

If `(max - min + 1) < N` then you know there's a duplicate. Otherwise ...

Because the range is N, the minimum item can go at `a[0]`, and the max item at `a[n-1]`. You can map any item to its position in the array simply by subtracting `min`. You can do an in-place sort in O(n) because you know exactly where every item should go.

Starting at the beginning of the list, take the first element and subtract `min` to determine where it should go. Go to that position, and replace the item that's there. With the new item, compute where it should go, and replace the item in that position, etc.

If you ever get to a point where you're you're trying to place an item at `a[x]`, and the value already there is the value that's *supposed* to be there (i.e. `a[x] == x+min`), then you've found a duplicate.

The code to do all this is pretty simple:

**Corrected code.**

```
min, max = findMinMax()
currentIndex = 0
while currentIndex < N
    temp = a[currentIndex]
    targetIndex = temp - min;
    // Do this until we wrap around to the current index
    // If the item is already in place, then targetIndex == currentIndex,
    // and we won't enter the loop.
    while targetIndex != currentIndex
        if (a[targetIndex] == temp)
            // the item at a[targetIndex] is the item that's supposed to be there.
            // The only way that can happen is if the item we have in temp is a duplicate.
            found a duplicate
        end if
        save = a[targetIndex]
        a[targetIndex] = temp
        temp = save
        targetIndex = temp - min
    end while
    // At this point, targetIndex == currentIndex.
    // We've wrapped around and need to place the last item.
    // There's no need to check here if a[targetIndex] == temp, because if it did,
    // we would not have entered the loop.
    a[targetIndex] = temp
    ++currentIndex
end while
```

That's the basic idea.

Comment: How do we know the list elements are in the range `min .. min+N-1`? I don't think that's stated anywhere in the original question.

Comment: The value could already be in its place accidentally. For example, `[6,4,3,2,5,2]` contains 5 at 5. In fact, the chance of that happening for at least one element exponentially approaches 1 as the length of the list grows.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think it is implied in my saying that the values in the list are bounded and the list is no longer than their range.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov But you can see in the pseudocode that we only check two elements for equality (and therefore, only ever report we found a duplicate) under the condition that their indices differ, so `[6,4,3,2,5,2]` doesn't actually pose a problem.

Comment: @DanielWagner The OP's first sentence says that the list elements are in that range. Or at least strongly implies it.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov I have supplied corrected code, with comments.

Answer (score 2):

For integers (and other [**`Ix`**-like types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ix.html#t:Ix)), you could use a mutable array, for example with the [**`array`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.3.0).

We can here use a [**`STUArray`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.3.0/docs/Data-Array-ST.html#t:STUArray) here, like:

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST

updateDups_ :: [Int] -> STArray s Int Bool -> ST s Bool
updateDups_ [] _ = return False
updateDups_ (x:xs) arr = do
    contains <- readArray arr x
    if contains then return True
    else writeArray arr x True >> updateDups_ xs arr

withDups_ :: Int -> [Int] -> ST s Bool
withDups_ mx l = newArray (0, mx) False >>= updateDups_ l

withDups :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
withDups mx ls = runST (withDups_ mx ls)
```

For example:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.ST Data.Array.ST> withDups 17 [1,4,2,5]
False
Prelude Control.Monad.ST Data.Array.ST> withDups 17 [1,4,2,1]
True
Prelude Control.Monad.ST Data.Array.ST> withDups 17 [1,4,2,16,2]
True
```

So here the first parameter is the maximum value that can be added in the list, and the second parameter the list of values we want to check.

Comment: Writing `updateDups` as a `foldr` will get you fusion, though I'm not sure if that'll work through the monad layer. Probably.